# Does a OneToOne and OneToMany need to be mapped on both sides in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

If I have a simple `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    @OneToMany
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

Does `Address` and `Car` need to have a `Person` field? Most tutorials show it this way, that there is a two-way communication.

But in my case I only need to have the Address and Cars in a Person, but don't need the Person in Address or Car.

How would you map it in Hibernate? Who should be responsible for `mappedBy` ?

Comment: @Amogh OK; But if I have no `Person` in a `Car` and I want to have the CAR table have the FK to PERSON, will Hibernate figure it out? Perhaps you could write an example of what you meant please?

Comment: Sorry for my first my comment.In `OneToMany` you have to keep `Person` in car, then only you can achieve one personId has many carIds.

Comment: @Amogh No, you don't. While you have to have a join column in the CAR table, the Car entity can be totally oblivious of it's owner. Take a look at the `JoinColumn` annotation. You can use it in the Person class to implement that.

Comment: @kostja, example added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unidirectional @OneToOne primary key association:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="person")  
public class person{  

@Id  
@Column(name="person_id") 
@GeneratedValue     
private Integer personId;  

private String name;  

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
private address address;

//getters & setters

}  

@Entity  
@Table(name="address")  
public class address{  

@Id  
@Column(name="address_id")    
private Integer addressId;  

private String street;  

//getters & setters

}
```

Unidirectional @OneToMany primary key association:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="person")  
public class person{  

@Id  
@Column(name="person_id") 
@GeneratedValue     
private Integer personId;  

private String name;  

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)  
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn 
private address address;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private List<car> cars;


//getters & setters

}
```

**Update**

It should be clear to you that How can an entity keep so many IDs in just one column?

Always keep in mind that many side will have single object for foeign key where as one side will have list to hold child objects.

So you have two options here:
1) Use a specific table to store relation between your One and Many entities. Something like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
private List<car> cars;
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-mapping

2) You can also say Many cars belongs to One person so in car class we also write like:

```
@ManyToOne
private person person;
```

http://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/hibernate-many-to-one-unidirectional-mapping-using-annotation/

This information is for one-to-many and many-to-one unidirectional mapping.

Comment: I m posting answer from my mobile so there may be some syntax msitake you may find.so please free to ask in case of any diff.

Comment: Thanks you; So the extra column with a foreign key will be always in `Address` and `Car` tables or in `Person` table?

Comment: @Queequeg, In `OneToOne` there will be no extra foreign key column in any table. In case of `OneToMany` The many side here in our case `car` will have foreign key. Answer is updated with proper explanation .

Comment: @Queequeg, and doing unidirection mapping or bi-direction mapping is up to you. depending on needs. If you want only `person` need to know which addressId and carId is mine then unidirection (as we r doing) is fine. But if you want `car` also want to know to which person I m belonging to then you have to do `OneToMany` at person side and `ManyToOne` at car side which is bidirectional

Comment: @Queequeg Very nicely explained by @Amogh, Read More @ `OneToMany` : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/ `OneToOne` : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-tutorial-using-annotation/

Comment: @Amogh thank you for your comments; regarding the two options you mention in the edit: in 2) I assume that it is impossible to specify a JoinColumn without having a Person member? And In 1) won't the CAR JoinTable collide with CAR table for the entity? Secondly, why do you only specify 1 @JoinColumn? Don't you need 2 - one for person id, second for car id?

Comment: @Queequeg Sorry again, You are correct in `JoinTable` CAR will collide with CAR I updated the answer. You can also specify `@JoinColumn` with `OneToMany` to make it unidirectional relationship.

Comment: Are you understood now or still in dark.sorry I was not explaining well coz of lack in english